# Multiple Computers on Multiple Networks Crashing because of Unknown Win Issue

Tags: windows, crash, windows-update, microsoft-office-2010

I am part of team of people who are experiencing a weird issue that we cannot seem to pin point the root cause of;

So far the only commonality between the computers seems to be Windows 7 and LabTech Software.

I, personally have seen the issue occur on 3 separate computers. It happens when you reboot the machine. However, we have a large network on machines on various clients and we are noticing the issue on a certain percentage of our clients, and then a certain percentage of their machines. It does not appear to be spreading, but it has affected a great number of computers.

One of the computers was unable to install windows updates, .NET seemed to have been turned off, unable to turn it on, event viewer was inaccessible, restoring windows worked the first few times and now the restore will not even work. (that computer is hosed after experiencing the crash 4 times)

Another computer, which I am currently on, is still repairing and rebooting into windows. I rebooted into a restore point from yesterday morning "after the crash." The user used the computer all day yesterday without issue. We decided that we would use it to perform some test on...
I booted it into safe mode and ran an MBAM scan.
I found 2527 threats and attempted to remove them (necessary reboot)
computer would not boot up, necessary restore.
tried to remove malware bytes which was still there, but could not, downloaded a removal tool recommended by MBAM, removed program, reboot necessary...
computer would not boot up, necessary restore.
I have had to restore the computer back to the same point in time several times now and can't seem to find a cause.
ran a rootkit scan, came back fine.
I am going to reboot the computer again now that I have been on it for a little while and see if needs to restored again.

We have seen Microsoft office try and install updates, computer is hosed upon reboot.
Windows updates has tried to install updates on some of the machines, computer is hosed.
Windows complains that it is running out of resources on some of the machines, hosed.
repair of most of the machines comes back saying that the ACPI.sys file is corrupt
We have reached out to Microsoft and they aren't sure what is going on either. They did some debugging and found that 144 sys files were missing from one of the machines in question.
most of the machines are running SEP, but not all of them.
I have seen an "Error 2908" involving Microsoft Office 2010
0xc000000e (and similar errors)

The symptoms appear to be wide spread at this point and are tough to narrow down.

We have tried virus scans, check disks, reaching out to Symantec, MS, etc...

I could really use some guidance here and would appreciate any help some is willing to provide.

As for Labtech, which people here are quick to assume is the culprit because its the only commonality. We don't use it to patch and we don't use it to script. I have reached out to their support system and they have never heard of this issue either.

thank you for taking the time to read this. I will promptly respond to whomever decides to help me out.

thank you!

Comment: Your computers are infected, must wipe out clean and start fresh

Comment: If you are finding 2527 actual malicious files and we are not talking about tracking cookies  then you have a serious infection on your network.  It is time to nuke every single machine from orbit, take the storage servers offline to nuke those from orbit, and restore everything machine by machine.  If system files are missing again, time to install a fresh installation, stop trying to tie the systems back together they are well beyond any help at this point.

Comment: 1 computer returned results from an MBAM scan, otherwise we can't find an infection anywhere. repairing the computers works, but who is to say it wont happen again? People are blaming this monitoring software, LabTech, but I haven't found one similar reported issue. It would be nice to pin point what happened, but at this point I'm fighting the current. I'm worried there is a larger issue, that we are over looking.

Answer (score 0):

it could be related to monitoring software if there aro no viruses. some of those monitoring apps could conflict with number of proccesses behid the curtain there were some similar issues with firewall software third party which behaved in that manor. try uninstall on some test machines and then check the systems.